# How to get Recovery without the Hardware key

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop

Apprently I am stuck in a known problem the [Cyanogen Bootloop](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/troubleshooting#Bootloop_problem).
The solution involves going into *recovery*, which is not possible since my "**volume down key**" is physically damaged.

Do I have any options of escaping the vicious Bootloop? Or did I officially brick it?

The model is: HTC Desire HD (HTC Ace)

Comment: Which is your phone model?

Answer (score 3):

Try booting while pressing the **back key**. That will get you into ***fastboot***, and you can access hboot (and hence recovery) from there.

If it worked try any solution among this..

**It depends on the cause of the boot loop**

Wipe cache and dalvik (depending on what recovery you look in different places for these. I think ClockworkMod may have wipe dalvik in advanced). TBH I think this is unlikely to do it, but is harmless.

If something has been corrupted in the ROM then reflashing the ROM (without wiping) will fix it.

If it's data corruption then a factory reset will do it.

Comment: the rom is CyanogenMod 7 so i don't think fastboot is even possible.

Comment: @AndreasPetersson Fast boot isn't dependant on the ROM.

Answer (score 3):

If you have fastboot, boot into that. You can then procede to wipe data while in fastboot mode by issues the `fastboot -w` command. You can then reboot the device using the `fastboot reboot` command.

Be aware that not all devices come with fastboot. If you can access ADB while the device is booting, then you can issue an `adb reboot recovery` command to reboot into the recovery menu that way.