# How can I get to recovery without Volume Up hardware button?

Tags: recovery-mode, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Or, 'My tablet's hardware "Volume Up" button is broken, now what?'

I'm trying to root an Asus TF300TG Transformer tablet (a 2012 model, unlocked) following [this guide on XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2617298):

- I have installed the USB drivers on my computer
- Rebooted tablet to fastboot
- Flashed the TWRP recovery without problems
- (Rebooted normally, verified that tablet still works as usual)
- Rebooted to fastboot again
- Got to the point where I should boot to the new recovery

That step requires me to press the Volume Up button to select the recovery option on this screen:

[image]

In my tablet, however, the button is broken (and has been for some years now). Is there a way to get into recovery without actually pushing it?

What I've tried:

- Pushing harder
- Pushing the other two HW buttons: Volume Down moves the selection, Power does nothing
- Connecting the keyboard dock: there is a Volume Up button, but it doesn't do anything in fastboot mode; none of the dock buttons do anything
- Connecting a USB keyboard via the dock: no keypresses seem to do anything in fastboot
- Rebooting to recovery using `fastboot reboot recovery`: invalid command
- Booting an image using `fastboot boot twrp.blob` (and various other recovery images from my computer): loaded to tablet, then failed (note the empty error message)

  ```
  downloading 'boot.img'...
  OKAY [  0.398s]
  booting... FAILED (remote: )
  ```

Is there a different way to get to recovery?

Comment: This seems related, but I was fortunate enough that the "normal" mode still worked: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36552/how-to-get-recovery-without-the-hardware-key?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

- boot the tablet normally
- enable USB debugging
- connect to computer by cable
- from the computer, run `adb reboot recovery`
- tablet reboots directly to recovery
- Done!

I was trying to issue this command in Fastboot (where it's not supported) instead of ADB (where it works).